# Cannot move out of borrowed content when matching on an Option of an enum

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm very new to Rust, so please bare with what I do not understand.
I'm trying to match on an reference to a struct. It has a field `op` of type `Option<Operator>`, where `Operator` is a defined enum. This is the code:

```
fn formatNodeName(node: &ComputeNode) -> String{
    match node.op{
        Some(ref operator) =>   format!("{}[label=\"{}[{}]\\n{}\"];",node.id, node.name, node.id, operator),
        _ =>    format!("{}[label=\"{}[{}]\"];",node.id, node.name, node.id)
    }
}
```

But I get the following error, which I sort of understand and sort of don't:

```
   src/codegen/graph_viz.rs:43:8: 43:12 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
src/codegen/graph_viz.rs:43     match node.op{
                                      ^~~~
src/codegen/graph_viz.rs:44:8: 44:16 note: attempting to move value to here
src/codegen/graph_viz.rs:44         Some(operator) =>   format!("{}[label=\"{}[{}]\\n{}\"];",node.id, node.name, node.id, operator),
                                         ^~~~~~~~
src/codegen/graph_viz.rs:44:8: 44:16 help: to prevent the move, use `ref operator` or `ref mut operator` to capture value by reference
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How should such thing be "properly" implemented to match?

Comment: The error you've given appears to be from a completely different part of your code.  Also, without a minimal test case, no one will be able to reproduce your problem.  *Blind guess*: try either removing the `&` or replacing it with `ref `.

Comment: Sorry i've posted a wrong error message.

Comment: For some reason I posted somthing totally different initially, my guess is I might have 2 stackoverflow windows open and posted the wrong ones. Nevertheless your suggestion with using ref resolved it so you an post it as an answer.